# Android Emulator Shutdown takes FOREVER

Tags: android, emulation

I need to poweroff/poweron emulator to perform test.  I get an endless message Shutting Down ...
that has been running 30 minutes+ on the emulator.  This is totally not working.  Is there any way to get emulator to shutdown or at least startup the emulator without an app.  I am trying to test app boot on startup, and I cannot get emulator to shutdown. So at least is there a way to start emulator without giving it an app to startup with. BTW, if there is someone who knows about the internals of the emulator on this board would you care to tell us what is going on during this 30+ minutes. I could have processed a gazillion db transactions in this time.  This is not slow, not even slothful it is something totally unworkable. Thanks

Comment: I don't believe it will ever shut it down.  I've let it run all night and it still goes.  To speed up the AVD, I've noticed that having a gaming capable graphics card makes a HUGE difference.  I can set up an AVD on my iMac that runs faster than any device I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse:

1. Open the Android Virtual Device Manager
2. Select your virtual device and hit the start button
3. In new window uncheck "launch from snapshot"
4. Launch

Comment: This does not work. After you start a virtual device from snapshot it just hangs. AVD is buggy beyond belief. In essence, there is no way to emulate android devices. You have to resort to physical devices.

Answer (score 0):

Open Android SDK and AVD Manager >  Click the Device you want > Click start button and it will open with no app running.

Generally the Emulator is slow(And with my experience EXTREMELY slow when running honeycomb).

Comment: I second the vote for "Generally the Emulator is slow" I try to avoid it if at all possible and do my testing on read devices.

Comment: Using hardware acceleration for the Emulator helps a lot: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to stop using the Android emulator and use the [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator. It is free and it is faster than testing on a physical device assuming your computer is decent. You can easily start and stop the emulator through VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem is to make sure that I close the AVD Manager and Android Studio windows first before I exit the Android Emulator. Works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

Choose "Cold boot" instead of "Quick boot".
If you are using Android Studio:

1. Open Tools -> AVD Manager
2. Click "Edit" of the device you want to boot
3. Click "Show Advanced Settings"
4. Find "Boot option", select "Cold boot"
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

In linux go to terminal and issue the following commands -

```
cd /home/username/.android/avd/<virtual device name>
sudo rm -rf *.lock
```

Here, I deleted the lock files from the virtual device directory to force the device to terminate.

Something similar process can be done on Windows and MAC.